# NPN transistor seems on even though base is grounded with resistor

Tags: led, pwm, npn

I have this very simple circuit, which behaves strangely. OC0A is a ~64kHz/50% PWM signal coming from an ATmega328P.

1. With the circuit as pictured, the LED lights up EXTREMELY dim even though R2 grounds the base of the transistor.
2. Removing the R2 resistor completely or replacing it with a wire turns the LED completely off.
3. With the R2 resistor present, but R1 resistor connected to Vcc instead of OC0A, turns the LED completely off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZDJV3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Could anyone help me understand why the LED lights up just a little bit when I power it from the PWM signal, with a resistor from base to ground?**

I know this circuit doesn't achieve much, but it was just an attempt at debugging another circuit which gives similar behavior. I think that understanding what is happening here would help me with the actual circuit.

Things to consider:

1. This is all on a breadboard
2. I am using an Arduino UNO
3. The circuit is powered from the 5V of the Arduino UNO, which is powered from my laptop's USB supply
4. No change in behavior was noticed whether the laptop is being recharged or not
5. No change in behavior was noticed when using a power bank
6. If I try to measure voltages of interest with my multimeter, the LED becomes even dimmer, but if you look very closely you can see it is still just a little bit on.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe enough collector-base (or other parasitic breadboard) capacitance to get a bit of base current to flow due to the PWM signal. A smaller value for R2 or a capacitor from base to ground should eliminate the issue if that's the cause.

Comment: If just removing R2 and leaving the base floating eliminates the issue, then maybe the ground end of R2 isn't well grounded.  Make sure it's right across the base-emitter leads and see if that helps.

Comment: The LED should be off. A few microamps leakage could cause it to glow. This can be from a bad transistor, prototype board or AC being picked up and rectified into DC.

Comment: Hi, Can you give us a pert number and a data sheet link for the LED?

Comment: Breadboard? C and B of transistor in neighboring rows? Maybe capacitiv coupling through the breadboard. couldn't you try to get a grounded row between the rows C and B of Q1 are in?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you made careful observations, and performed some tests to diagnose the issue.

The difference between connecting *R1* to the ATmega output and to V+ is the *frequency* of the voltage: DC vs. a waveform, likely with steep sides, having harmonics well into the RF. This can cause the lamp to light if RF has leaked across the transistor, or if the grounds for *R2* and emitter have a voltage drop between, due to inductance (a ground-loop issue).

To see if RF is the cause of the dim glow, put a small capacitor, perhaps 1 or 10 nF, from LED/*R1* junction to ground, and/or tie the grounds of *R2* and *Q1* *closely* together.

Comment: I tried your suggestion about the small capacitor and it worked. Could you please confirm if I correctly understood your thought process: you added the capacitor to create an RC low-pass filter with R1, and you chose its value so the cut-off frequency (-3db) is about 64kHz thereby "eliminating" the harmonics. I tried to do some research to understand your explanation, but only found ressources that are too complicated to understand at my skill level. Would you have some recommendations to links/videos/books to help someone inexperienced get some sort of a grasp of this RF stuff? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @AmineKchouk It's not so complicated. The breadboard has lots of capacitance (okay... picoFarads -- but it's enough) between each and every row on it. It's not the best place to test your 64 kHz ideas. Suppose there is some capacitance between the joint node that DrMoishe suggested to you and the BJT base. This would be sufficient, without DrMoishe's suggested capacitor, to drive the LED well into dozens of microamps, if not more. So it would be visible. Now, if you put a 10 nF to ground at the same node, that bypasses the current that would have gone to the base, now sending it to ground.

Comment: @AmineKchouk The two mental pictures I have in mind look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7r8S.png). Just to be clear. The one on the left will drive the LED so that you can see it (kind of.) The one on the right will definitely turn off the LED as C1 will essentially bypass the current far far more aggressively than C3. So what used to trickle through C3 to the base will now go entirely to ground and the base won't get tickled anymore. Don't need a fancy book.

Comment: @AmineKchouk, your analysis was more thoughtful than my own! As you state, bypassing the LED shunts the RF to ground, but I just took an "educated guess" for the capacitor value, rather than calculating the 3 dB point. Thank you for responding, and I'm glad it worked.

Comment: Wouldn't also help a capacitor parallel to R2? (always assuming Q1 is not defective).